# Fills three Excel columns based on numbers in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba, enumerate

I think I know what I want to write, but unfortunately VBA syntax etc always confuses me... I guess I just don't get enough practice.

I want to fill three columns in Excel based on the values in another sheet. The two columns are Room and Module. There are several different values for Room and several different values for module. Each Room can contain 0 or more of each type of Module. I want to fill two columns (A and B) based on the number of times each Module appears in each room. I would like to fill column C with a sequential number for each type of module.

E.g. this is the source data:

```
            Room 1  Room 2
Module A    2       4
Module B    8       3
```

And this is the desired end result:

```
Room    Module  
        Type        No.
Room 1  Module A    1
Room 1  Module A    2
Room 1  Module B    1
Room 1  Module B    2
Room 1  Module B    3
Room 1  Module B    4
Room 1  Module B    5
Room 1  Module B    6
Room 1  Module B    7
Room 1  Module B    8
Room 2  Module A    3
Room 2  Module A    4
Room 2  Module A    5
Room 2  Module A    6
Room 2  Module B    9
Room 2  Module B    10
Room 2  Module B    11
```

I think that what I want to write is something like:

```
For each R in Range(B:1 to C:1)
For each M in Range(A:2 to A:3)
M = 0
For each C in Value(R:M)
X = (R*M)+C
M = 0+1
Cell A:X = Value(Cell(R))
Cell B:X = Value(Cell(M))
Cell C:X = M
Next C
Next M
Next R
```

I'm sure this contains errors but I hope I've explained and shown what I'm trying to do.

All constructive help and feedback welcome.
Cheers :)

Comment: Start by using `Option Explicit` and declaring all your variables.

Comment: Hi @cybernetic.nomad thanks for that tip, but that's not really what I was hoping for help with (although it is useful for my learning, so I appreciate it). I was hoping that someone could show me how to write my pseudo-code in VBA :)

Comment: Showing you how to write code in VBA is too broad a topic for this site. There are plenty of online tutorials and you can use those. If you hit a specific roadblock then is the time to come back here and ask a question to find out how to solve that specific problem

Comment: Okay, that's one way to look at it. Apart from that, is my pseudo-code going to work if I get the syntax right?